# Running server-side python in JS: difficulty with pico

Tags: javascript, python, webserver

I have webpage that needs to run some computation on start up. I want to keep this computation on the server side so the client cannot access the source code. I discovered [pico](https://github.com/fergalwalsh/pico), a module that is supposed to be "a bridge between server-side python and client side JavaScript".

I have a simply test.py:

```
import pico

def hello():
    return "Hello World"
```

My JavaScript is also simple:

```
pico.load("../../../test.py");
pico.main = function() {
    var displayMessage = function(message){
        console.log("hello2");
        console.log(message);
    }
    test.hello(displayMessage);
}
```

"../../../test.py" is the relative location of the python script to the pico folder

I then run "python -m pico.server" on the command line. When I go to my web page, open inspector, and go to the console I get the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i". 'i' is presumably from the first line import. Note that this same error happens if I don't run the pico.server command.

Any help would be great, as well as suggestions for alternative methods of doing this serverside vs clientside.

Comment: How does the web page include the JavaScript? Do you also load the pico client as per the example on the pico page you reference?

Comment: the javascript is located in the index.html file, called during a user input event (moving a slider). I've put a console.log statement in that area to verify it gets there when the slider is used. I'm not sure what you mean by "load the pico client". Which part of the pico tutorial are you referring to? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you change the first line from `import` to something else ? like `raise AssertionError` and check if the `i` changes to `r` ?

Comment: Yes, previously I had some other code there and it changed to the other letter. It seems it just errors on the first character of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I may have an answer for you, however I have not been able to replicate the same error.

- **`pico.load`** does not seem to work when file extensions are included in the argument, this is due to the function being designed to load sub-modules directly (i.e. *module.sub_module*) as in the [pico API](https://github.com/fergalwalsh/pico/wiki/client.js):

> pico.load(module, [callback])
>
> Load the Python module named module. The module will be available as a global >variable of the same name.
>   Submodules may be loaded by using dotted notation e.g. module.sub_module

To make sure I included ".py" file extension on the pico test page I have been working on and it failed to load the module, so this may be a problem if you are using the file extension.

- Another possible issue was mentioned in a comment by **holderweb**. In the first [pico example](https://github.com/fergalwalsh/pico/wiki/Example-1:-Hello-World) HTML the file **client.js** is included in an external `<script>` tag, this includes the functionality required to use pico. So you must have something similar to the following tag in your index.html head section:
  `<script type="text/javascript" src="/pico/client.js"></script>`

For more insight I would be interested in seeing what/if the server logs at command line when the error occurs, and also the contents of your index.html page. Hope this helped!